# Create Linear gradient form one color code using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, linear-gradients

I am adding linear background dynamically to div. I have one color code in rgb format. How do you get end color code with slight different from colde which I have saved in backend using jquery. I am adding background like this

`background: linear-gradient(-58deg, #0057a0, #00b8e1);`.

Basically I am adding linear background like this

`style="background: linear-gradient(-58deg, '+Card.bgColor+', '+Card.bgColor+');"`.

Card.bgColor is a rgb value which is coming from backend. I wanted to just apply darker or lighter colorshade as a end color of gradient. Please help me.

Comment: share some code what you have tried so far!

Comment: I am just adding linear background like this style="background: linear-gradient(-58deg, '+Card.bgColor+', '+Card.bgColor+');". Card.bgColor is rgb value which is coming from backend. I wanted to just apply darker or lighter colorshade as a end color of gradient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are possible to use third party plugin then you can try something with this stuff [TinyColor](http://bgrins.github.io/TinyColor/) which provides functions to get lighten or darken color codes on what ever input you given.

```
tinycolor("#f00").lighten().toString(); // "#ff3333"
tinycolor("#f00").lighten(100).toString(); // "#ffffff"
```